# "Maximum number of connections already opened" Error Message

Tags: asp.net, iis, database-connection, sybase, powerbuilder

I developed a web site using Sybase PowerBuilder V12.0 Classic and the output is deployed and converted to ASP.Net (ASPX) web pages.

The Database connection is configured and used properly as the data is displayed in the web application using DataWindow Objects and is a direct connection with sybase Database Server using Dsedit Tool and No ODBC is used.

I edited The Sybase Databse configurations related to remote servers and connections to be more than the default value which was 25 although the real number of users will not exceed that in the same time.

Recently I received an error message when some users connected to the web site and after making valid logins:-

The Error Message is:-

Maximum number of connections already opened

> ct_connect(): user api layer: external
>   error: The maximum number of
>   connections have already been opened.

I am confused about the causes of that error as I think I had made all configurations needed and I checked evey option and setting related to the Number of Connections in The Sybase Database server, The Application Deployment Settings in Sybase PowerBuilder V12.0 Classic, and The IIS Settings.
I use Windows Server 2003 and the IIS version is 6.0 in the Web Server.

I appreciate any suggestion or hint to solve that problem and Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all really. There are too many concurrent connections to your database.
Perhaps your application doesn't close all of them. If you do not close database connections, connections can remain opened for some time.

Now, I never developed for Sybase, but that is what is usually the case with MSSQL server when this error occurs.

Comment: Yes, I understand the error message but I was asking about the configuration needed to increase the number of connections to remove this error. Anyhow, I had found the solution as it is an option in the database profile before deploying the web application. The default was 25. I changed it and it works fine. Thanks for your general answer.